# Source for learning TDD

Tags: tdd

I'm fascinated by TDD. I looked some stuff up on the internet, saw the video of uncle bob where he made the bowling application and now I want to go further. In my normal jobs I don't build bowling applications. Mostly I build crud/data heavy applications. Those are build in multiple layers etc.etc.

Does anyone knows a book, video, tutorial etc that describes the use, does and dont's etc for TDD in CRUD centered applications?

Comment: How to test just about any type of Java-like code: http://www.amazon.com/books/dp/0131177052

Comment: Do you write tests at all at the moment? If not, start doing it. If so, try to write them first.

Comment: I didn't see the video but if you now think it only applies to bowling applications it was probably bad ;-) The process should be the same for your application. I know TDD (regarding unit tests) as a simple cyclic process: Write new test => Make test work => Refactor => Repeat until you can't think of any new test for your specification.

Comment: The video is very good to explain the concept of TDD. Where it fails is to transfer the knowledge to a real world example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the best resources for real-world TDD I know is James Shore's free [Let's Play TDD](http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Lets-Play) video series.

> Let's Play: Test-Driven Development is a screencast series featuring Java, test-driven development, and evolutionary design. It chronicles the development of a real software project, warts and all.

Comment: Thank you. This looks like an interesting serie.